# measure the memory usage in C# projects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an algorithms written in C# ,I want to measure the memory usage by these algorithms.
could you please help me ?

Comment: For future: It is generally recommended to show results of your research on the topic - i.e. search for title of your post - https://www.bing.com/search?q=measure+the+memory+usage+in+C%23+projects and see if there are existing articles. Not demonstrating what you already know may lead to downvotes - please refer to [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor) for more recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualStudio built in profiling tools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx or install a 3rd party profiler such as JetBrains profiler: https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/